# GoDaddy htaccess remove .php specific page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have spent probably close to 10 hours trying to figure out this .htaccess problem and I am starting to think it might be a GoDaddy issue. I am trying to rewrite www.361orc.info/login.php to www.361orc.info/login. I am building a social media site for a class and I have already gotten profile pages to rewrite from .info/profile.php?name=username to .info/username. My .htaccess file is below:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine  On

RewriteRule ^login?$ /login.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php  [NC]
```

## UPDATE

Another possibility, depending on GoDaddy's hosting platform, would be:

(I can't guarantee it, as I don't have access to the GD server)

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine  On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This works perfectly is there a way I can remove the trailing forward slash though? It is now displaying as: http://www.361orc.info/login/ and I would prefer it to be: http://www.361orc.info/login

Comment: ^When I remove the / then it rewrites it in the users browser which is not what I want.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^login$ login.php  [NC]`  -   Check out an example here: http://www.checkourprogress.co.uk/alerts/test/burger

Comment: ^That is doing a rewrite for the client as well. Like I said I have found multiple working examples from others but they do not work on my site which is why I fear it might be some weird GoDaddy issue.

Comment: Without having access to a GoDaddy server, I am unable to replicate it. However, it's working fine on my hosting platform.

Comment: Now no page is loading and it is saying the page has a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the magic

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that looks a little too universal for me. I only want to rewrite login.php and createAccount.php. I have other php pages that this would probably catch which I wouldn't want it to.